# Problem with installation Ubuntu on my old MacBook Air

Tags: system-installation, macbook-air

This is the errors I'm seeing at boot:
[nouveu 0000:02:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101078000 on channel -1 [ofedf000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 0000000b [VRAM_LIMIT]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KstQw.jpg)

In case you can't read it, the errors are like this:

> nouveu 0000:02:00.0: fb: trapped read at 0101078000 on channel -1 [ofedf000 unknown] engine 06 [BAR] client 08 [PFIFO_READ] subclient 01 [IN] reason 0000000b [VRAM_LIMIT]

The system I have this issue with is an old MacBook Air with these specs:

> Late 2010
>   2.13GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
>   4 gb 1067 MHz DDR3 RAM
>   NVIDIA GeForce 320M 256 MB

Can somebody help me try and resolve this issue?